# sorting strings largest and smallest

Tags: c

i cant get the program to properly sort the strings into largest and smallest of all the user inputs

im having issues with the if statements and how they are recording the smallest and largest

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
int finish = 0, longest=0, smallest=0, count =0;
char word[20], smallest_word[20], largest_word[20];
while (0 == finish)
{
    printf("enter word:");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", &word);
    if (count == 0)
    {
        strcpy(smallest_word, word);
        strcpy(largest_word, word);
    }


    if (strcmp(word, smallest_word)<smallest)
    {
        strcpy(smallest_word, word);
        smallest = strcmp(word, smallest_word);
    }
    if (strcmp(word, largest_word) > longest)
    {
        strcpy(largest_word, word);

        longest = strcmp(word, largest_word);

    }


    if (strlen(word) == 4)
    {
        finish++;
    }
    count++;
}
printf("smallest word: %s\n", smallest_word);
printf("largest word: %s\n", largest_word);

getch();
return 0;
}
```

program runs just doesn't record the largest and smallest values correctly

Comment: The C standard specifically states that: `fflush(stdin);`  is undefined behavior

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", &word);`  This causes the compiler to output the message: "untitled.c:13:13: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[20]’ [-Wformat=]"  to fix this, use: `scanf("%s", word);`  this is related to the fact that referencing an array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.   Also,  1)  always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Note: the `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful input format conversions  (cont)

Comment: (cont)  2) when using the format specifiers '%s' and/or '%[...]'  always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer because they always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior.  Suggest:  if( scanf("%s", &word) != 1 ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf to input word failed\n" );`  Such a statement will usually be followed by 'cleanup' and `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: @user3629249 - you are right on the standard and `fflush(stdin)`, but the code contains `conio.h` - so, you can guess what MS allows as an *extension* to the C standard. See [MS-docs `fflush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fflush?view=vs-2019)

Comment: the languages 'C' and 'C++' are two different languages.  Per the posted code, it is for the 'C' language, so suggest removing the 'c++' tag

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, The header file: `conio.h` is not what allows the `fflush( stdin )`  Rather the visual studio compiler allows it

Comment: The reference to `conio.h` was to imply compiling on windows (with the VS compiler, `cl.exe`)

Comment: `strcpy(smallest_word, word);
        smallest = strcmp(word, smallest_word);
    }` is same as `strcpy(smallest_word, word);
        smallest = 0;  }`

Comment: babySteps, Post input used, output seen and expected.  Without that, your post is unnecessarily unclear.

Comment: bruh this is semantics, i need help with the actual logic of the program @everyone

Comment: on stackoverflow.com.  when asking a question about a run time problem, as this code is doing, you need to post a [mcve]  Otherwise the question is 'off topic'.  So it is not 'semantics' but rather a requirement of the web site

Comment: regarding: `count++;`  This is executed every time through the loop, so in ~2gig words it will overflow.  in C, overflow of a signed integer is undefined behavior.  Lets' not take that risk.  Suggest moving that statement to inside the `if()` that checks if the variable is 0

Comment: can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header file `conio.h` and its `getch()` are not part of standard C and you should probably avoid using them.
See [Why is getch not portable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582070/why-is-getch-not-portable) and [Why must we refrain from using conio.h? Is it obsolete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329485/why-must-we-refrain-from-using-conio-h-is-it-obsolete).

---

Your loop seem to go on till the user enters a word of length exactly 4. No need to use a separate variable like `finish` for it. Just use a `break` statement. 
ie, instead of

```
if (strlen(word) == 4)
{
    finish++;
}
```

do

```
if (strlen(word) == 4)
{
    break;
}
```

and you can get rid of that `finish` variable.

---

`scanf()` expects pointers to buffers where the scanned input need be stored as parameters after the format string. With

```
scanf("%s", &word);
```

you are giving pointer to a pointer as `word` itself is a pointer since array names in C decay into pointers to their first element. So `word` by itself points to the first character stored in the `word[]` array.

Use

```
scanf("%19s", &word);
```

instead. 19 is the width specifier. 19 was chosen since the size of `word` is `20` and we need `1` character space to store the `\0` denoting the end of string. This can help avoid buffer overflow.

You may also want to check the return value of `scanf()`. It returns the number of successful assigments like

```
if( scanf("%19s", &word)!=1 ) {
    //Something went wrong.
}
```

See [What happens if I use "&" with string in scanf function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332187/what-happens-if-i-use-with-string-in-scanf-function).

---

Usage of `fflush()` on `stdin` leads to undefined behaviour in C as it is meant to be used only on output streams. See [Using fflush(stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin).

---

[`strcmp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) just returns a negative number if the first argument is lesser than the second and a positive number if first argument is greater than the other. These numbers could be anything. You need not save the return value of `strcmp()`.

So instead of

```
if (strcmp(word, smallest_word)<smallest)
{
    strcpy(smallest_word, word);
    smallest = strcmp(word, smallest_word);
}
if (strcmp(word, largest_word) > longest)
{
    strcpy(largest_word, word);
    longest = strcmp(word, largest_word);
}
```

do

```
if (strcmp(word, smallest_word) < 0)
{
    strcpy(smallest_word, word);
}

if (strcmp(word, largest_word) > 0)
{
    strcpy(largest_word, word);
}
```

---

So, you could change the program to

```
char word[20], smallest_word[20], largest_word[20];
for(int count=0; ; ++count)
{
    printf("enter word:");
    scanf("%19s", word);
    if (count == 0)
    {
        strcpy(smallest_word, word);
        strcpy(largest_word, word);
    }

    if (strcmp(word, smallest_word) < 0)
    {
        strcpy(smallest_word, word);
    }

    if (strcmp(word, largest_word) > 0)
    {
        strcpy(largest_word, word);
    }

    if (strlen(word) == 4)
    {
        break;
    }
}
printf("smallest word: %s\n", smallest_word);
printf("largest word: %s\n", largest_word);
```

Answer (score 1):

Both your logic and syntax have some problems.

Here strcmp(src,dst) returns 0 if both strings are same else some positive or negative number when src>dst and dst>src respectively.

And scanf() needs address of variable and array name itself gives the address of 1st element of the array so no need of using '&'.

And for logic part, you should continue the loop after increasing the value to avoid extra confusion and comparisons.

```
  if (count == 0)
{
    strcpy(smallest_word, word);
    strcpy(largest_word, word);
}
```

And there is no need of variables longest and smallest as instead of them both you can use zero.

The completely working code I edited for you is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
int finish = 0, longest=0, smallest=0, count =0;
char word[20], smallest_word[20], largest_word[20];
while (0 == finish)
{
    printf("enter word:\t");
    scanf("%s", word);
    if (count == 0)
    {
        strcpy(smallest_word, word);
        strcpy(largest_word, word);
        count++;
        continue;   //To ensure in first time loop ends here 
    }


    if (strcmp(word, smallest_word)<0)
        strcpy(smallest_word, word);
    else if (strcmp(word, largest_word) > 0)
        strcpy(largest_word, word);



    if (strlen(word) == 4)
    {
        finish++;
    }
    count++;
}
printf("smallest word: %s\n", smallest_word);
printf("largest word: %s\n", largest_word);

getch();
return 0;
}
```

[image: Screenshot of output ::]

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
if (strcmp(word, smallest_word)<smallest)
```

and

if (strcmp(word, largest_word) > longest)

`strcmp()`  returns 0 or >0 or <0.   It does not return a pointer to anything.  a returned value <0 indicates that the first parameter comes alphabetically before the second parameter.  A returned value of 0 indicates the two parameters are equal.  A returned value of >0 indicates the first parameter comes alphabetically after the second parameter.

Comment: doesnt help much

Comment: neither the OPs code nor my answer are actually trying to sort the strings.  They are only trying to determine which string is earliest (and latest) alphabetically  The main problem with the OPs code is trying to compare the return value from `strcmp()` to anything other than > 0, =0, <0

Answer (score 0):

You can see the size of a string using `strlen()` from `string.h` library.